# Combining two mostly identical rows in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains data like below:

| Name | ID | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1001 | Accounting |
| Joe | 1001 | Marketing |
| Mary | 1003 | Administration |
| Mary | 1009 | Accounting |

Each row is uniquely identified with a combo of Name and ID. I want the resulting table to combine rows that have same Name and ID and put their dept's together separated by a comma in alpha order. So the result would be:

| Name | ID | Dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1001 | Accounting, Marketing |
| Mary | 1003 | Administration |
| Mary | 1009 | Accounting |

I am not sure how to approach this. So far I have this, which doesn't really do what I need:

```
SELECT Name, ID, COUNT(*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY Name, ID
```

I know COUNT(*) is irrelevant here, but I am not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated! By the way, I am using PostgreSQL and I am new to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is an aggregate function for string concatenation with PostgreSQL. Find documentation [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/). Try the following:

```
SELECT Name, ID, string_agg(Dept, ', ' ORDER BY Dept ASC) AS Departments
FROM employees
GROUP BY Name, ID
```

Comment: yes this works! Although, it's not giving the dept's in alpha order. Any ideas on how to do that? I had tried this before but couldn't figure out the alpha part :/

Comment: I just had a read through the documentation and you can add an order by clause to the string_agg function. I'll update my answer to include. Won't be 100% sure on the syntax without testing though